# Orchard CMS Showing Only Drafts

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I would like to show only the draft version of documents when the user makes requests to a specific subdomain.  The idea is that when requests are made to the "www.mysite.com" domain, we show the published version of documents but when requests are made to the "wip.mysite.com" subdomain, we show only the draft version of the documents throughout the site.  What in the Orchard CMS extensibility points would I need to tap into to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because by default Orchard's ContentManager service returns published items. Now everywhere a content item is displayed (when a page is opened or a widget is displayed) the default behaviour is used: that's why you only see published items.

Normal items are displayed by `Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController`, containers from `Orchard.Core.Containers.Controllers.ItemController` and widgets from `Orchard.Widgets.Filters.WidgetFilter`. You could create your own controllers that fetch drafts an re-route requests to them, also you could override `Orchard.Widgets.Services.WidgetsService` to fetch draft widgets.

That said you probably don't want to do this :-). Maybe you are interested in something like explained in [this issue](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18898)?

Comment: Yes, the site preview functionality as you suggested will work nicely and is exactly what I would need.  I wish I could have that feature now.

Comment: Yeah, having that would be really great.

Comment: For now I think I would have to create my own item controllers and re-route requests to them like you said based on a cookie setting to determine what version documents to show.  I will need to create an admin UI to set the cookie value.

Comment: Yes, sadly. BlogController is an additional entry point for displaying blogs, so you should then override that or BlogService too.

Comment: Any advice on how I can handle the alias routes without affecting the routes that need to be handled by the default Orchard routes?  Right now, my solution intercepts all routes including the admin page routes.  I am not sure how I can handle just the normal content view routes that have aliases without affecting admin, edit, and other routes.  Aliases make it hard to establish routing patterns.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'd take the approach of re-routing item display routes. That should work by just specifying a route with higher priority, regardless of aliases used.